# How can I make the last else statement only execute once? (It is executing 5 times)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] items = { "Ham", "Ranch", "Plantains", "Soda", "Spaghetti" };
    double[] prices = { 1.99, 2.99, 3.99, 4.99, 5.99 };
    int[] inventory = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };

    System.out.printf("We have these items available: Ham, Ranch, Plantains, Soda, Spaghetti");

    System.out.printf("\nSelect an Item ->");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String item = input.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].equals(item)) {
            System.out.printf("\nYes, we have %s. Price:%s Inventory:%s", items[i], prices[i], inventory[i]);
            System.out.print("\nHow many would you like to purchase? -->");
            int quantity = input.nextInt();
            if (inventory[i] >= quantity) {
                double total = quantity * prices[i];
                System.out.printf("\nThank you for your purchase of: Item: %s \nYour total bill is: %2.2f",
                        items[i], total);
            }else {
                System.out.printf("\nSorry, we only have Inventory:%s of Item: %s", inventory[i], items[i]);
            }

        }else {
            System.out.printf("\nSorry, we don't have %s", item);
        }

    }
}
```

}

So, the last else statement is printing out 5 times rather than one, I am not sure what to do in order to fix it. Is it in between the right brackets?

Comment: You can not make this determination inside the loop, you can only do it after the loop when you have looked through all the items. Add a `boolean itemWasFound = false;` that you set to `true` when you find it. Then *after* the loop, check `if (! itemWasFound) { ...; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to test if the element isn't present **after** the loop with a `boolean` variable yourself. Also, if it is found there is no need to continue looping (so `break`). And use `%n` with `printf` to get a newline. Like,

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].equals(item)) {
        System.out.printf("%nYes, we have %s. Price:%s Inventory:%s", items[i], 
                prices[i], inventory[i]);
        System.out.print("%nHow many would you like to purchase? -->");
        int quantity = input.nextInt();
        if (inventory[i] >= quantity) {
            double total = quantity * prices[i];
            System.out.printf("%nThank you for your purchase of: Item: %s %n" 
                    + "Your total bill is: %2.2f", items[i], total);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%nSorry, we only have Inventory:%s of Item: %s", 
                    inventory[i], items[i]);
        }
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.printf("%nSorry, we don't have %s", item);
}
```